# How can I get sklearns subset multi-label accuracy in Keras?

Tags: keras

Sklearn calculates the [`accuracy_score`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ab93d65/sklearn/metrics/classification.py#L112) ([docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html)) for multi-label problems as a subset accuracy: Each prediction is only counted as correct if every predicted label is correct. The default `'accuracy'` of Keras is the binary accuracy:

```
def accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.equal(y_true, K.round(y_pred)), axis=-1)
```

The values are too high. I think `K.equal` calculates the equality on each element, right? How do I make it calculate the equality per vector?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to write a [callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/) for this. Here's an example.

```
import numpy as np

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.callbacks import Callback

from sklearn.metrics.classification import accuracy_score

n_labels = 3
n_samples = 20
n_feats = 10

x = np.random.normal(size=(n_samples, n_feats))
y = np.random.randint(2, size=(n_samples, n_labels))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, input_shape=(n_feats, )))
model.add(Dense(n_labels, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(
    loss='binary_crossentropy', 
    optimizer='rmsprop', 
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

class SkLearnHistory(Callback):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.accuracy = []

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        y_pred = np.round(self.model.predict(self.x))
        y_true = self.y

        score = accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
        self.accuracy.append(score)

        return

sklearn_history = SkLearnHistory(x, y)
keras_history = model.fit(x, y, epochs=5, verbose=0, callbacks=[sklearn_history])

keras_history.history['acc']

# [0.46666663885116577,
#  0.48333334922790527,
#  0.51666665077209473,
#  0.58333337306976318,
#  0.60000002384185791]

sklearn_history.accuracy

# [0.14999999999999999, 0.20000000000000001, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]
```